# Why does my IBM 5154 have an undulating wave?

Tags: repair, crt-monitor

My IBM 5154 had some blown capacitors in the power supply (the AC line filters). It worked, though I decided I should replace the caps in the power supply just to be safe. I went ahead and replaced all of the electrolytic capacitors as well (they were out of spec).

Put it back together and it works, sort of. I can clearly see the picture that is supposed to be there but the blacks are not black in EGA graphics mode and there is an undulating wave. In non-graphics (text) mode, the blacks are black but the undulating wave is still there.

Here's [a video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/RmYJF2KSLEAMwD678). How can I further troubleshoot this?

[image: GIF capture by Spektre]

Comment: Current leakage?  Did you clean off all flux after soldering?  You might try asking over on electronics.se

Comment: No, I didn't. I knew there was something I forgot.

Comment: OK, I cleaned what little flux was there, but it didn't change. It also makes a very high-pitch humming noise.

Comment: Here be dragons.  I really think you should be asking this over on electronics.se

Comment: Vertical waves = supply voltage ripple. Pincushion distortion, small image and high brightness = excessive EHT voltage. Hope the screen isn't producing x-rays! Suspect the B+ rail has lost regulation. Perhaps you put a cap in the wrong way around?

Comment: Note that if you find any reversed caps they should be discarded and replaced.

Comment: I quadruple-checked the polarity of all of the caps; they're correct. I'm testing the power supply in isolation to avoid x-rays; hopefully I didn't just get cancer...

Comment: Please be careful.

Comment: As an aside, also look out for cold solder joints (they'll look dull, not shiny).  These can be fixed by reflowing the solder at a sufficient temperature.

Comment: After much fuss, I discovered that the -6.3V output has very little (positive) voltage. All of the positive outputs are fine.

Comment: hmm the sweeping coils does not provide accurate sweeping (so they are not driven by triangle wave (the curved shape of the image instead of rectangle)) most likely your trimmers and/or potentiometers are either a bit off or just dried/oxidated out. The overvoltage can be caused by the same thing. See related QA: [CRT Geometry Adjustment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5445/6868)  but beware if your caps where blown and monitor was running for a time after it might caused another damage in the electronics (like blown resistor or transistor ...).

Comment: also during the recaping did you disconnect some shielding in order to get access to PCB?

Comment: I did, though I put them all back before trying it out.

Comment: Figured it out; was dumb. Answered my own question down below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was because I forgot to plug a jumper into a socket that switches it from a 240V AC input to 120V AC input (socket M5). I simply forgot to plug it in. That's not the ONLY thing I did wrong, but it's the one that mattered.

Here's a complete list of ways in which I nubbed this up, for future readers benefit:

- I forgot the 120 V AC plug (see above)
- I tested the power supply without a dummy load, [possibly damaging it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80547/operating-a-switched-mode-power-supply-without-a-load) and causing all of the output voltages to be way too high (~1.5x, once I corrected the above)
- I discharged the capacitors with my finger (ouch!)
- I discharged the capacitors with a screw driver a half-dozen times, [probably damaging them](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/why-shouldnt-electrolytic-capacitors-be-short-circuited) (I now made myself [a discharging thingy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/52289/how-to-safely-discharge-high-voltage-42-v-capacitors))
- I forgot to clean off the flux

The good news is, my monitor is as good as new! Well, as good as it was before I decided I would "improve" it by replacing the capacitors (granted, two line filter capacitors had actually blown up, so it wasn't without reason). The picture is still off-center and too blue, but I'll save those adjustments for another day...